# Angular form submit - All fields are being submitted as null values

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-forms

I have a angular form which I'm trying to submit. It submits successfully, but all of the properties are null values. Theres no validation being applied currently.

Here is the component

```
export class AdvertComponent implements OnInit {

  property: Property;
  photo: Photo;
  user: User;
  advertForm: FormGroup;

  constructor(private advertService: AdvertService, private alertify: AlertifyService, public authService: AuthService,
    private formBuilder: FormBuilder) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.createAdvertForm();
  }

  createAdvertForm() {
    this.advertForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      town: ['', Validators.required],
      county: ['', Validators.required],
      address: ['', Validators.required],
      postcode: ['', Validators.required],
      eircode: ['', Validators.required],
      propertyType: ['', Validators.required],
      sellingType: ['', Validators.required],
      price: ['', Validators.required],
      bedrooms: ['', Validators.required],
      bathrooms: ['', Validators.required],
      size: ['', Validators.required],
      buildingEnergyRating: ['', Validators.required],
      description: ['', Validators.required],
    });
  }

  submitAdvert() {
        this.property = Object.assign({}, this.advertForm.value);

    this.advertService.createAdvert(this.authService.decodedToken.nameid, this.property).subscribe(() => {
      this.alertify.success('Success');
    }, error => {
      this.alertify.error(error);
    });
  }
}
```

This is the angular form.

```
<div class="container">
    <form [formGroup]="advertForm" (ngSubmit)="submitAdvert()">
        <h2 class="text-center text-primary">Fill out the form below</h2>
        <hr>

        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="town" placeholder="town">
          <div class="invalid-feedback">Please select a town.</div>
        </div>
         <div class="form-group">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="county" placeholder="County">
            <div class="invalid-feedback">Please select a county.</div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="address" placeholder="address">
            <div class="invalid-feedback">Please select a address.</div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="postcode" placeholder="postcode">
            <div class="invalid-feedback">Please select a postcode.</div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="eircode" placeholder="eircode">
            <div class="invalid-feedback">Please select a eircode.</div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="propertyType" placeholder="propertyType">
            <div class="invalid-feedback">Please select a property type.</div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="sellingType" placeholder="sellingType">
            <div class="invalid-feedback">Please select a sellingType.</div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="price" placeholder="price">
            <div class="invalid-feedback">Please select a price.</div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="bedrooms" placeholder="bedrooms">
            <div class="invalid-feedback">Please select a bedrooms.</div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="bathrooms" placeholder="bathrooms">
            <div class="invalid-feedback">Please select a bathrooms.</div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="size" placeholder="size">
            <div class="invalid-feedback">Please select a size.</div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="buildingEnergyRating" placeholder="buildingEnergyRating">
            <div class="invalid-feedback">Please select a Building Energy Rating.</div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="description" placeholder="description">
            <div class="invalid-feedback">Please select a description.</div>
        </div>

        <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

The submitAdvert() method is the function that is hit when the form is submitted. Any ideas on what the issue is here?

createAdvert method from the advert service which is being injected into the advert component.

```
  createAdvert(id: number, property: Property) {
    return this.http.post(this.baseUrl + id + '/' + 'advert', {property});
  }
```

Comment: First step would be to see if this.property has anything in it before calling the service. Also, is the failure at the server level, or is no data being passed to the service?

Comment: this.property is only calling the instance of the property model. The form successfully submits as I have server-side no validation at present. A record creates, but it's null records.

Comment: can you make a stackblitz? It'll be easier for us to help you out

Comment: Are you saying your database record is null, or the form values are null? I have checked the code over and I can get a values when the form is submitted.

Comment: @Jack_b_321 Both. The form is valid when I submit it. But this my my JSON response on submit => {"town":null,"county":null,"address":null,"postcode":null,"eircode":null,"propertyType":null,"sellingType":null,"price":0,"bedrooms":0,"bathrooms":0,"size":0,"buildingEnergyRating":null,"description":null,"userId":4}

Comment: stackblitz here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ckgdgh there doesn't seem to be an issue with the code the console logs show the values are never null?

Comment: I console.logged it on my app and it's populating there. But it's not populating 'this.propery' for submission for some reason.

Comment: @AndreMacNamara the stackblitz I linked to shows this.property being populated? I don't understand the need for 'property' anyway as it is a direct copy of 'advertForm.value' just do `const property: Property = this.advertForm.getRawValue()` and use that for your API request

Comment: It's being populated when I console.log it, but when it's passed to the route its null for some reason

Comment: @AndreMacNamara so is the value null when it is passed to your createAdvert method? If so can you please edit the post with the code for that method.

Comment: Done @Jack_b_321

Comment: @AndreMacNamara answer posted

Answer (score 1):

You can submit your form even if it's not valid. By checking `this.advertForm.valid` you can block your form from submitting.

https://angular.io/guide/form-validation

You can check specific controls of your form to be valid by doing `this.advertForm.get('county').valid`. More details in the link shared above.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`Forms`](https://angular.io/guide/form-validation) `invalid` property to disable the submit button, which returns true or false based on the forms validation so the example code like:

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit [disabled]="advertForm.invalid">Submit</button>
```

and if you want that error message for each control should be dynamic then you can use `valid` property with the `ngIf` directive of FormControl like:

```
<div class="invalid-feedback" *ngIf="!advertForm.get('town').valid">
    Please select a town.
</div>
```

[`Stackblitz`](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ysjbps)

Answer (score 0):

Remove the braces around '{property}' it is already an object and does not require any braces, code below:

```
 createAdvert(id: number, property: Property) {
    return this.http.post(this.baseUrl + id + '/' + 'advert', property);
 }
```

Comment: Still the same result

Comment: I'm so confused at this stage tbh

Comment: The data is even in the payload

Comment: That suggests it's something to do server side. Are you able to provide the code for the endpoint you're hitting?

Comment: If you can see the data being passed in the payload of the request then it is definitely a server side issue.